# Usage of '@@' syntax in python

Tags: python, decorator

I ran into the double @@ symbol in the following code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py

I understand that the `@` is used as a decorator. But I can't seem to find any information on the use of `@@`?

Comment: That's inside a string literal. It's just text. A documentation generator or some other tool might assign a meaning to it, but not Python itself.

Comment: presumably used to generate this doc page https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.rnn#Base_interface_for_all_RNN_Cells

Comment: [It's also deprecated.](https://www.tensorflow.org/community/documentation#generating_python_api_documentation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@@` is used only in docstrings not in code. It is no valid Python syntax.

An external tool uses this for generating links to other classes in the documentation.

Comment: [It's deprecated](https://www.tensorflow.org/community/documentation#generating_python_api_documentation): "The @@member_name syntax is deprecated and no longer generates any docs."

Comment: Languages are free to define syntax.